# Windows Mobile - Hide Application

Tags: windows-mobile

I am developing an application for enterprise which can be installed on employee phones to track usage of phones and enforce certain security policies on phone.

My application needs to be hidden. It should not be shown in:

1. Running Programs in Task Manager
2. Program Files

How to do above using .NETCF 2.0 and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The "Running Programs" applet shows the captions of top-level windows.  Don't have a caption (i..e set it to String.Empty) and you won't show up.
2. Program Files is a folder.  If you don't want to show up there, don't put the app (or a shortcut to the app) in that folder.

Comment: First one is working nicely. I am confused about second. Can you please tell me exact steps for creating CAB file such that application folder does not show up program files?

Comment: Just modify the CAB's INF file (the thing CABWIZ uses as an input to generate the CAB) and 1) remove any shortcut and/or 2) change the target install path.  I can't be more detailed without seeing your INF file.

Comment: I changed install path to Windows folder. I am now putting my application in startup using Registry (using LaunchXX). Is there any known issue in starting up application using Registry? I read one of your article (http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx) that suggests to write Native application that calls actual application.

Comment: I would use a native launcher app to ensure that the CLR can load.